# java not allowing for the use of all 8gb of ram

Tags: java, ram, pae

I have a 32bit version of Ubuntu server with PAE active allow for the full use of the 8gb of RAM but I can't use more than 2gb of RAM in Java. I run the command

```
java -Xms6G -Xmx7G -jar server.jar
```

and I get the error:

```
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms6G
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

do I need to change something with Java? The server is 32bit so PAE is active to allow for the server to use all the 8gb of RAM.

Comment: PAE only means the kernel can use more than 4GB. Each process is still limited to 32-bit address, hence can only address 2/3/...GB depending on how much address is reserved for kernel space

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you have a PAE kernel doesn't really matter here, a 32 bit JVM suffer this limit, you can try to adopt a 64 bit memory model on a JVM by invoking

```
java -d64
```

but this will probably fail if you have a 32 bit *only* JVM. So get yourself a 64 bit JVM if you want to solve this.

Comment: To get a 64bit JVM, though, you'll need a full 64bit OS, which would require a reinstallation of Ubuntu.

Comment: @LordofTime it's also possible to install 2 kernels/OS in the same partition, but it's not an easy thing to manage and also I would not do that on a server. 64 bit OSs are the must if you want to setup a server this days ...

Comment: Eeeyup.  Why else would I say you'd need a full 64bit OS?  :P